# How to get deterministic train results in Doc2Vec?

Tags: python, gensim, doc2vec

I am using Doc2Vec to analysis some paragraph and wish to get deterministic vector representation of the train data. Based on the [official documentation](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/doc2vec.html), it seems that I need to set the parameters "seed" and "workers", as well as the PYTHONHASHSEED environment variable in Python 3. Therefore, I wrote the script as follows.

```py
import os
from gensim.models.doc2vec import TaggedDocument
from gensim.models import Doc2Vec


def main():
    # Check whether the environment variable has been set successfully
    print(os.environ.get('PYTHONHASHSEED'))

    docs = [TaggedDocument(['Apple', 'round', 'apple', 'red', 'Apple', 'juicy', 'apple', 'sweet'], ['A']),
            TaggedDocument(['I', 'have', 'a', 'little', 'frog', 'His', 'name', 'is', 'Tiny', 'Tim'], ['B']),
            TaggedDocument(['On', 'top', 'of', 'spaghetti', 'all', 'covered', 'with', 'cheese'], ['C'])]

    # Loop 3 times to check whether consistent results are produced within each run
    for i in range(3):
        model = Doc2Vec(min_count=1, seed=12345, workers=1)
        model.build_vocab(docs)
        model.train(docs, total_examples=model.corpus_count, epochs=model.epochs)
        print(model.docvecs['B'])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    os.environ['PYTHONHASHSEED'] = '12345'
    main()
```

The problem is that within each run it does produce deterministic results, but when I run the whole script again it gives different results. Is there any problem with my environment variable setting, or am I missing out something else?

I am on Python 3.6.5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe setting `PYTHONHASHSEED` inside your code is too late: it needs to be set **in the OS environment**, before the Python interpreter runs at all. When Python launches, it checks for this to decide whether **all** dictionaries during this execution will use the specified randomization seed. (It isn't rechecked later, for each subsequent dictionary creation.)

But also, note that you generally **shouldn't** force determinism on these algorithms – but rather make your evaluations tolerant of small run-to-run jitter. Large jitter can be an indication of other problems with the sufficiency of your data or metaparameters – but forcing determinism hides this valuable indirect signal of model strength.

There's a bit more discussion in Q11 & Q12 of the gensim project FAQ about these issues:

https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/wiki/recipes-&-faq#q11-ive-trained-my-word2vecdoc2vecetc-model-repeatedly-using-the-exact-same-text-corpus-but-the-vectors-are-different-each-time-is-there-a-bug-or-have-i-made-a-mistake-2vec-training-non-determinism

Comment: Hi, I would be glad if I could ask another related question (please let me know if I am supposed to create a new post). Like what you have said, the difference in train results may be rather small from run to run. However, say if I have used a document D for training and obtained its vector representation D_v from `model.docvecs`; D_v2 = `model.infer_vector(D)` is quite different from D_v. I thought D_v and D_v2 should be similar. Is my understanding wrong or is there something that I missed out?

Comment: Yes, they should be quite similar - in particular, if you query trained vectors from the model via `model.most_similar(positive=[D_v2,])`, the `tag` for the same text in training should be the top result (or in the top few). If this is **not** the case, there may be other problems during training or inference. Enable `INFO`-level logging for training, & review logs to ensure the expected number of texts, doc-tags, words, etc are processed. Ensure you're using a recent `gensim` with all recent inference fixes. Ensure you're passing a list-of-tokens to inference, & consider raising `epochs`.

Comment: The tag for the same text did not come to top, but after updating gensim to a newer version the problem seems to be solved now. My previous version of gensim was 3.4.0 (which seems to be the latest version available on conda), and I reinstalled 3.7.1 using pip (later version gives the "C extension not loaded" warning in Anaconda environment). Thank you so much for the detailed explanation!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can should use the following code to fix PYTHONHASHSEED

```
import os
import sys
hashseed = os.getenv('PYTHONHASHSEED')
if not hashseed:
    os.environ['PYTHONHASHSEED'] = '0'
    os.execv(sys.executable, [sys.executable] + sys.argv)
```